# SQL: SELECT FROM multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 10 tables communicating between them with parent keys an I am trying to pull out all the information that I need.

This is the query that I am using right now:

```
SELECT a.date_in, a.date_out, b.name, b.phone, b.birthdate,
b.country, b.hotel, b.room_nr, b.passport_nr, c.email,
d.size, e.name, GROUP_CONCAT(g.service), GROUP_CONCAT(h.service)
, GROUP_CONCAT(i.time), GROUP_CONCAT(j.location)
FROM reservation a, rider b, user c,
bike_size d, bike e, services_reservation f, services g,
bike_shipping h, bike_shipping_reservation i
, bike_shipping_location j WHERE a.rider_id = b.id
AND b.user_id = c.id AND a.bike_size_id = d.id AND
d.bike_id = e.id AND a.id = f.reservation_id AND
f.services_id = g.id
AND h.id = i.bike_shipping_id AND a.id = i.reservation_id
AND i.bike_shipping_location_id = j.id
AND a.id = 80
```

The problem is that all the columns where I use GROUP_CONCAT function, get duplicated many times. For example:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(g.service) column
Road SPD,Road SPD,Bike Helmet,Bike Helmet,TT Bar,TT Bar,Garmin Edge 
810,Garmin Edge 810
```

should be

```
Road SPD,Bike Helmet,TT Bar,Garmin Edge 810
```

Any ideas how I can fix it? is my database scheme good?

SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bc033/33

Comment: Added the MySQL tag for you, but try not to forget to specify your specific database when you ask other SQL questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DISTINCT in your GROUP_CONCAT statements

```
SELECT a.date_in, a.date_out, b.name, b.phone, b.birthdate,
b.country, b.hotel, b.room_nr, b.passport_nr, c.email,
d.size, e.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.service), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT h.service)
, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.time), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT j.location)
FROM reservation a, rider b, user c,
bike_size d, bike e, services_reservation f, services g,
bike_shipping h, bike_shipping_reservation i
, bike_shipping_location j WHERE a.rider_id = b.id
AND b.user_id = c.id AND a.bike_size_id = d.id AND
d.bike_id = e.id AND a.id = f.reservation_id AND
f.services_id = g.id
AND h.id = i.bike_shipping_id AND a.id = i.reservation_id
AND i.bike_shipping_location_id = j.id
AND a.id = 80
```

Comment: your welcome if my answer helped you out please consider accepting it.  here is a link about how/when/why to do so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `DISTINCT` IN GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT a.date_in, a.date_out, b.name, b.phone, b.birthdate,
b.country, b.hotel, b.room_nr, b.passport_nr, c.email,
d.size, e.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.service), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT h.service)
, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.time), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT j.location)
FROM reservation a, rider b, user c,
bike_size d, bike e, services_reservation f, services g,
bike_shipping h, bike_shipping_reservation i
, bike_shipping_location j WHERE a.rider_id = b.id
AND b.user_id = c.id AND a.bike_size_id = d.id AND
d.bike_id = e.id AND a.id = f.reservation_id AND
f.services_id = g.id
AND h.id = i.bike_shipping_id AND a.id = i.reservation_id
AND i.bike_shipping_location_id = j.id
AND a.id = 80
```

Comment: Did you try this in his sql fiddle?  this doesn't work, g.service and h.service then become groupings and instead of concatenating the strings of those fields unique it replicates the rows to the number of combinations of h.service and g.service.

Comment: @Matt  I didn't t try on fiddle.yes u r right sorry i make groupings instead of finding distinct values.Corrected

Comment: So now it is correct, but I had already answered that prior to you answering the question.